# build gem5 on ubuntu22.04 protoc version mismatch

Tags: ubuntu-22.04, gem5, protoc

Trying to build gem5 on ubuntu 22.04.. have installed all the dependencies required other than HDF5 C++ libraries..

protoc version is 3.20.3
ubuntu is 22.04.3 LTS

```
$ which protoc
/home/jasneets/anaconda3/bin/protoc

$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
<empty line>

$ pwd
/home/jasneets/study/comparch/gem5$ pwd
    
$ python3 `which scons` build/X86/gem5.opt -j 9
...
In file included from src/mem/probes/mem_trace.cc:43:
build/X86/proto/packet.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
   12 | #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
      |  ^~~~~
build/X86/proto/packet.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
   13 | #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
      |  ^~~~~
build/X86/proto/packet.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
   14 | #error your headers.
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from src/mem/probes/mem_trace.cc:43:
build/X86/proto/packet.pb.h:72:12: error: ‘PROTOBUF_CONSTEXPR’ does not name a type
   72 |   explicit PROTOBUF_CONSTEXPR PacketHeader_IdStringEntry(::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::ConstantInitialized);
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
build/X86/proto/packet.pb.h:183:16: error: ‘ClassData’ does not name a type
  183 |   static const ClassData _class_data_;
      |                ^~~~~~~~~
build/X86/proto/packet.pb.h:184:43: error: ‘ClassData’ in ‘class google::protobuf::Message’ does not name a type
  184 |   const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::Message::ClassData*GetClassData() const final;
      |                                           ^~~~~~~~~
build/X86/proto/packet.pb.h:206:3: error: ‘PROTOBUF_NODISCARD’ does not name a type
  206 |   PROTOBUF_NODISCARD std::string* release_value();
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
build/X86/proto/packet.pb.h: In member function ‘ProtoMessage::PacketHeader_IdStringEntry& ProtoMessage::PacketHeader_IdStringEntry::operator=(ProtoMessage::PacketHeader_IdStringEntry&&)’:
build/X86/proto/packet.pb.h:86:9: error: ‘GetOwningArena’ was not declared in this scope
   86 |     if (GetOwningArena() == from.GetOwningArena()
```